# Transferring funds to India from US

Tags: taxes, india, international-transfer

I am an Indian citizen ending my PG studies in US as I'm unable to return to the US after an overseas trip because of visa issues.

I wish to transfer savings from my US bank account to a savings account in India. I do not have a savings account in India yet. It is taxed in US. Is there a limit to how much can be transferred? Will any taxes be owed in India?

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit and no taxes applicable in India, if you get the funds within 7 years from your return to India.